# Laravel getting class on view without passing from controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a pivot table `post_profil`e that contains the hearts (likes) of each post.

**Post.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function profilesHearted()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

**Profile.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function profileImage()
    {
        $imagePath = ($this->image) ? $this->image : 'profile/czyhBQu2YWX6gvBivZrnEs2ORoBwr3d9mzkwxk8k.png';
        return $imagePath; 
    }

    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function heartedPosts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

The main view which shows all posts of followed users is working along with the heart button but underneath I want to show **liked by <x> and 30 others**, where `x` is first follower of the user if any of the user's follower hearted the post.  I tried many ways to get `x` but I am a bit lost.

This is `PostsController.php` index function which leads to the view:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = auth()->user()->following()->pluck('profiles.user_id');
    $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->with('user')->latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts', 'users' ));
}
```

What I tried to do but deleted eventually after failing is get each post in foreach loop and check if each `$post->heartedProfiles(contains($users))`, but this doesn't work this way. So another way I tried is in my view ie, `index.blade.php`

```
@foreach($users as $userid)
    User::select('id')->where('profile_id', $userid)->first()
        ->profile->profilesHearted->find($post->id)
@endforeach
```

Which doesn't work because `User` class cannot be used directly in view without passing.

I'm sure there is a simple and cleaner way to do this in Laravel. This is my first time using Laravel and ORM programming so really felt lost. Took the FreeCodeCamp Instagram clone tutorial and understood the basics. All I need is to give me some idea to get started.

Comment: I would like to help, but can you state in one sentence what exactly you are trying to do? You want to show "Liked by John Doe and 30 others"?

Comment: Yes i want to show that. To pass this from PostsControllermphp  Post-heatredprofiles.find(user.followers). My English is not that good for explaining so i always ends up with essays sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with many to many you need to use the pivot functions, so you would do like so

```
Post::profilesHearted()->wherePivotIn('profile_id', $users)->first()
```

Not checked the code but hopefully it will give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks this is what i did and its working. Please let me know if there's a cleaner way to write this code. 
 @ php
               $heartedUser = $post->profilesHearted()->wherePivotIn('profile_id', $users)->first();
               @endphp

               @if( $heartedUser ) 
                   <p>Liked by {{ App\User::where('id', '=', $heartedUser->pivot->profile_id )->first()->username }} and {{ $post->profilesHearted->count()-1 }} others. </p>